# Facing problem while trying axios with pug template

Tags: node.js, express, axios, pug

I'm trying to use axios with pug template but facing a problem.
here is my code:
base.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block head
      meta(charset='UTF-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
      link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
      title Natours | #{title}
  
  body
    // HEADER
    include _header
        
    // CONTENT
    block content
      h1 This is a placeholder heading
      
    // FOOTER
    include _footer
      
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')
    script(src='/js/login.js')
```

and in login.js

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http:127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/login',
      data: {
        email,
        password
      }
    });

    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  login(email, password);
});
```

but everytime i'm trying to submit the form i'm getting this error in console.log
"
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
"

Comment: Somebody is also doing the Natours nodejs course from Udemy I see ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [Content Security Policy headers for script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) to allow your site to load scripts from a different domain, in this case `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`.

You can do this either in your webserver (if you're using one) or in the Node.js application.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src <source>;
```

In Node/Express it would be something like:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', 'script-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com');
```

You can also use a library such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header

Comment: Really thanks for your reply.I'm kinda new in node like doing my first node couse and faced this issue.so can you tell me a bit details like where in server i should use "res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', 'script-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com');"? i used that in controller after your answer but still facing the same problem. than i install express-csp-header but i got this error "SyntaxError: Identifier 'expressCspHeader' has already been declared".

Comment: oh sorry i copy pasted twice "const { expressCspHeader, INLINE, NONE, SELF } = require('express-csp-header');" and so got "SyntaxError: Identifier 'expressCspHeader' has already been declared" error.now that fixed but still i'm getting error as i mentioned in my question

Comment: Thanks.it worked after using "app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
  );
  return next();
});"